# Mat checkbox.. CheckAll and Uncheck All - Angular Material 6

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular6

I have a tree of checkboxes like:

[image]

What i want to achieve:

- When **"Select All"** has been clicked, then all checkboxes under it shall be checked and **FormArray** value shall be updated and vice-versa for **"Unselect All"**
- When i select **Master Checkbox1 or Master Checkbox2** then its children shall be selected and **FormArray** shall be updated.

**PS.**: Checkboxes are being generated dynamically from service.

Below is the form structure:

```
fb.group({ departments: this.fb.array([]) })
```

To store permission checkbox values i have below in departments FormArray

```
fb.group({
  department: ['', Validators.required],
  permissions: this.fb.array([])
});
```

I tried it like to toggle a variable in HTML to switch checked state but i am not able to update formArray - permissions value by doing that.

Form markup is as below:

```
<div formArrayName="departments">
      <div *ngFor="let ctrl of createUserForm['controls'].departments['controls']; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i" class="mb10">
        <mat-expansion-panel class="selected-department d-none" id="departmentBar-{{i}}">
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
              <h4 id="departmentBar-{{i}}-header" class="m0 fw420"></h4>
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>
              <mat-icon (click)="deleteDepartment(i, ctrl)">close</mat-icon>
            </mat-panel-description>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <div class="mat-expansion-content">
            <!-- TimePiece Previliges Block-->
            <div class="header-permissions" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between start">
              <span class="group-header">TimePiece Previliges</span>
              <span class="select_all">Select All</span>
            </div>
            <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="businessEntityTimePiecePermissions" let-timepiece let-mati="index">
              <div class="mt10">
                <mat-checkbox class="permission_type checkbox">
                  <strong>{{ timepiece.type }}</strong>
                </mat-checkbox>
                <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="timepiece.operations" let-operations>
                  <mat-checkbox class="full-width d-block permission_operations" (change)="onPermissionCheckBoxToggle($event, operations.id, ctrl.controls.permissions, mati)">
                    {{ operations.name }}
                  </mat-checkbox>
                </ng-template>
              </div>
            </ng-template>
            <!-- // TimePiece Previliges block ends -->
            <!-- SEO Previliges block -->
            <div class="header-permissions" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between start">
              <span class="group-header">SEO Previliges</span>
              <span>Select All</span>
            </div>
            <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="businessEntitySEOPermissions" let-timepiece>
              <div class="mt10">
                <mat-checkbox class="permission_type">
                  <strong>{{ timepiece.type }}</strong>
                </mat-checkbox>
              </div>
              <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="timepiece.operations" let-operations>
                <mat-checkbox class="full-width d-block permission_operations" (change)="onPermissionCheckBoxToggle($event, operations.id, ctrl.controls.permissions)">
                  {{ operations.name }}
                </mat-checkbox>
              </ng-template>
            </ng-template>
            <!-- // SEO Previliges block ends -->
          </div>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
        <mat-form-field class="width-85p" id="departmentInput-{{i}}">
          <input type="text" required matInput placeholder="Search..." formControlName="department" [matAutocomplete]="autoGroup">
          <mat-error *ngIf="ctrl.controls.department.invalid">This field is required</mat-error>
          <mat-autocomplete #autoGroup="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of filteredUserDepartmentList | async" [label]="group.casinoName" [id]="group.beID">
              <mat-option [value]="dept.DEPARTMENTID" [ngClass]="{'selected': dept.selected}" *ngFor="let dept of group.departments" (click)="departmentSelected(group, dept, i)">
                {{ dept.DEPARTMENTNAME }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-optgroup>
          </mat-autocomplete>
          <mat-progress-spinner class="mat-spin abs-position-loader" mode="indeterminate" diameter="20" strokeWidth="2" *ngIf="priviligeRequestProgress"></mat-progress-spinner>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any leads please?

Comment: You need to include markup for checkboxes as well as structure of permissions - obvious markup would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Antoniossss ... Markup added

Answer (score 1):

> I tried it like to toggle a variable in HTML to switch checked state
>   but i am not able to update formArray

You should not do that, in fact, you should do exact the oposite - update your form values - checkboxes in UI will reflect those changes.

You are not sharing most viable information of how exactly form for permissions look alike so actual content of `permissions: this.fb.array([])` would be helpfull. However assuming that permissions is one array it would be something like that:

```
 for(//iterate over indexes/controls you want to check/uncheck){
  form.get(`permissions.${index}`).setValue(true); //true to check, false to uncheck
}
```

that as well assumes that permissions are boolean flags.

Comment: If you look for comment <!-- TimePiece Previliges Block--> then that is the form of permissions.. and you can see Select All as well